# Eloquent - Distinct multiple columns but not exact

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following records in my database:

`[user_id, ip]
[1, 127.0.0.1]
[NULL, 127.0.0.1]`

I want the result of a distinct call to return 1 row and not 2.

For example `Model::groupBy('user_id', 'ip')->get()->count();` will return `2` when I want it to return `1` because there is a duplicate in the ip column.

Likewise if the data was:

`[user_id, ip]
[1, 127.0.0.1]
[1, NULL]`

I would want the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->whereNotNull('user_id')` to filter out those values if that's fine for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I still need those counted. For example if I had the following records:

`[user_id, ip]
[NULL, 127.0.0.1]
[NULL, 127.0.0.1]`

The result again should be `1`

Comment: Then group by `user_id` only and filter `[NULL,NULL]` if you need it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this gives me the exact same result?

Comment: The thing is, the more you write, the less I'm sure about what you mean. Questions. Is there a point of storing a user_id with no IP address and IP address assigned (two rows)? Think about it. Maybe it would be better to normalize the db, add constraints, whatever.

Comment: Basically I want distinct `user_id's` unless `=== NULL` in that case I need to check if the `ip` already exists against another row to see if it's unique or not